# Unable to dismiss followers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have two followers in my game, and for no reason at all they started glitching. When I press E on them, it has an option to tell them to follow me, no option to open inventory, and no option to dismiss them. When I choose the option for them to follow me, it does nothing. I tried disabling every follower related mod, I've tried dismissing followers through console, I tried reloading a save, and I even tried disabling and re-enabling the followers. Worse part is, if I go recruit a new follower they work fine, but I can't do anything with these two. Any way to fix this?

Comment: What follower mods did you have installed when you encountered this issue?

Comment: @galacticninja I have, Pick default Follower Armor, Kuertee Simple Multipler followers, and I have one that has a popup that says "best skills? etc" before going to dialogue, but I cant seem to find which mod does that.